# Iterate json through $.each function TypeError

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, each

I get the response from php as:

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"category_id":"category id must not be empty","name":"name must not be empty","uri":"uri must not be empty","price":"price must not be empty","status":"status must not be empty"}}
```

and want to display the errors:

```
form.submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $('.help-inline').remove();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), {'data': data}, function(result) {

        if (result.success == true) {
            console.log('true');
        } else {
            $.each(result.errors, function(label, error) {
                console.log(label+' '+error);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But it throws me `TypeError: e is undefined`

On older versions it works, but on 1.8.3 is not.
What I'm doing wrong?

My php code is:

```
            $errors = $post->errors('');
            $this->response->body(json_encode(array(
                'success' => FALSE,
                'errors' => $errors,
            )));
```

$errors is associative array:

```
array(5) (
    "category_id" => string(29) "category id must not be empty"
    "name" => string(22) "name must not be empty"
    "uri" => string(21) "uri must not be empty"
    "price" => string(23) "price must not be empty"
    "status" => string(24) "status must not be empty"
)
```

Comment: Post your php code since we have to see how the request is processed on server side.

Comment: server code modified, TypeError still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `result.errors` is an array with just one element, the one you want to iterate with `$.each` , so just replace your following line:

```
$.each(result.errors, function(label, error) {
```

for this one:

```
$.each(result.errors[0], function(label, error) {
```

that should do what you want.

Comment: I've tried that already, TypeError: result.errors is undefined

Comment: Your jsbin link is working fine here on Chrome, displaying the expected results and with no javascript errors. What error are you getting? what browser are you on?

Comment: @UAMoto your javascript is cached. Make a deep reload.

Comment: @eicto Sorry I wrongly thought the jsbin link was posted by UAMoto, thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON, your errors array appears to only ever contain a single element which is an object with properties, try using:

```
$.each(result.errors[0], function(label, error) {
```

Comment: @UAMoto what line is the error on? I don't see any `e` variable in use.

Comment: TypeError: e is undefined

...eturn t?u.length:u?nt.error(e):L(e,a).slice(0)}function at(e,t,r){var i=t.dir,s=...

jquery.min.js (line 2)

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would cause that. It's a jQuery/browser issue unfortunately, unless you have any other Javascript that is breaking jQuery..

Answer (score 0):

PHP and response seems to be ok, but i do not see where you will say for javascript that you will use json data type. You can verify that when you use console.log(result) code. And see if your result is an object or string. As

```
form.submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $('.help-inline').remove();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), {'data': data}, function(result) {
        console.log('Result is: ' + typeof(result));
        if (result.success === true) {
            console.log('true');
        } else {
            $.each(result.errors, function(label, error) {
                console.log(label+' '+error);
            });
        }
    });
}, "json");
```